# How to know which child an item is for its parent

Tags: android, listview, get-childitem

I have a multiple choice list view and for its adapter I have designed a layout file. I have an image view in the layout and when it's clicked, I want to know **what child** of the list it is. I mean the child id for the its parent which is the list to further use the method list.getChildAt(???). can anyone tell me how to get that?

The image is independent of the list view and for its onClick attribute I've written a different method that changes image view resource... How can I know which child that a particular imageView is when I click on it?

In the XML layout I have this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/choice_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="deleteSelected" />
```

And here is a part of deleteSelected method:

```
public void deleteSelected(View view) {

    icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.choice_image);

    list.getChildAt(???); \\ To know which child the view is        

}
```

I have set the adapter as follows:

```
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_choice_multiple,
            R.id.choice_text, terms) {

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        icon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.choice_image);

        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete_off);

        icon.setTag(R.drawable.delete_off);

        return v;
    }
});
```

How can I set the id for each image view so I can access it by getID() method within deleteSelected()?

Comment: **What do you want to achieve?** Clarify it, may be there is better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

ListView has a [getFirstVisiblePosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition%28%29) method, using that you can calculate the child position based on its position in the list view (which is a parameter passed in to the onItemClicked method of the listener).

```
int childIndex = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() - position;
```

If you're clicking on a child of the row view (View used in the ListView, created by the adapter), then you need to know which position the row belongs too - simplest way is to store the position in the tag of the child when you set the onClickListener

Comment: The point is I've written a method that in it I don't have access to "position". Furthermore getFirstVisiblePosition() always returns 0 for me.

Answer (score 0):

Basically first you will have to set an onClickListener for your list-item's ImageView in getView() of the Adaptor.

Now with onClickListener you get the view that is clicked as function parameter to onClick(). Set a different background for this view (ImageView) object.

Hope this is clear. Let me know.

Comment: You know I don't want to write an onClickListener because the image view onClick handler is different from list item on click handler and I don't want to click the whole item to get the position but just the image view.

Comment: Have edited the answer. Please see if it suits your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: You are writing that the click happens on the ImageView. The ImageView is not associated with the ListView.
So there is no relationship between your click or any element in the ListView.
When clicking on the ImageView, though, the onClick receives a reference to the ListView itself. So what you are trying to achieve? Please be more precise.

Comment: How to get the reference and the position of the clicked item?

Comment: If the click is triggered on your ImageView and the ImageView the click is not associated with a position of the ListView. It's a click on an image. All Android knows is that an image was clicked. Android doesn't know about your intention. When it is about unchecking the last modified item of your list, you should save that modified item. But then you have the reference to it and don't have to iterate over the ListView. This is just the point that is not clear to me: Is the Image clicked? Then there is no association.

Comment: I have the list child count and I have the view in my method "deleteSelected". Doesn't view have any property that is unique and can be used by list like list.getChildAt(view.???)?

Comment: No. You will have to provide it, e.g.setId(int), or setTag(int key, Object obj) when creating the view in your adapter. You can then use the findViewByID or findViewByTag - Methods.